# How to fix C++ linker error with no explaination

Tags: c++, class, oop, linker, linker-errors

I have a C++ project that won't compile, and the following 2 errors are produced:

> Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals
>
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl
>   StartWindow::~StartWindow(void)" (??1StartWindow@@UEAA@XZ) referenced
>   in function "public: void __cdecl StartWindow::`vbase
>   destructor'(void)" (??_DStartWindow@@QEAAXXZ)

StartWindow is a class I have defined, but currently it is never instantiated or included anywhere in the project. Deleting the class allows the project to compile, but if this class is within the project it won't.

I will include the code for the class in case I am missing something:

.CPP File

```
#include "StartWindow.h"

StartWindow::StartWindow()
{
    setImmediateDrawMode(false);
}

void StartWindow::onDraw()
{
    clearScreen(WHITE);

    EasyGraphics::onDraw();
}
```

Header File:

```
#pragma once

#include "EasyGraphics.h"

class StartWindow : public EasyGraphics
{
public:
    StartWindow();
    ~StartWindow();

private:
    virtual void onDraw();
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the implementation for the destructor for `StartWindow`. In your implementation file (.cpp file), append:

```
StartWindow::~StartWindow(){
    //if your destructor is non-trivial, include definition here
}
```

Comment: Or `StartWindow::~StartWindow() = default;`

Comment: Also true, yes, if the destructor is trivial